# Taskbar pinned file shortcuts become invalid after moving the underlying files

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts, jumplist

When you move a file that is pinned to the taskbar (in a jumplist) that pinned shortcut becomes invalid. Clicking it results in the usual error for broken shortcuts:

[image]

How can I move a big number of pinned files to a new location and have the pinned items stay valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Windows sets this in the registry as binary data. The only way is to first unpin the documents, then move them, and then pin them again.

Theoretically you could move the files and create a directory junction so windows keeps thinking the files are in both places, but I assume you are moving the files to a different location because you don't want them to be at the first location.

Comment: OK, I'll accept this answer because it is likely that there is just no way to do this. I will reconsider if someone comes up with a better idea.